# How to upload to SFTP user's Home directory using Spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'm trying to upload a file via SFTP using Spring Integration (version 4.1.2).
Does anyone know how to configure the **sftp:outbound-channel-adapter** so that the file gets uploaded automatically to user's home directory without indicating the full directory path in the remote-directory's attribute (ex: remote-directory="/home/sftp_user")?

Comment: How about just try `remote-directory="/"`?

Comment: Or `.`, probably - `/` might point to the root, unless chroot is in effect.

Comment: Thank you both Artem and Gary for your responses. "/" indeed uploads to root. I have not tried "." but an empty string worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that the remote-directory must be set as an empty string.
Please note that the following won't work as it fails the XML model validation:

```
    <sftp:outbound-channel-adapter
        ...
        remote-directory=""
        ...
    />
```

I ended up reading the remote-directory from a configuration property which I set as an empty string.